# Можно ли не изменяя исходники совместить проект на C# с monodeveloper который был написан в Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, linux, monodevelop

Можно ли не изменяя исходники совместить проект на C# с monodeveloper который был написан в Visual Studio ?

Есть проект open source написанный на Visual Studio под Windows. Мне его под свои нужды доработать нужно, запускать его буду под Windows скорее всего, сейчас дорабатываю на виртуальной машине в Windows, но это не очень удобно (оперативки не хватает, виснет часто вплоть до перезагрузки жесткой...) Хотелось бы перенести весь проект на Monodeveloper что бы можно было запускать и разрабатывать под линуксом. В проекте Gui через wpf реализован. есть много еще чего (не во всем разбирался даже), много сторонних библиотек и прочего... Если кому интересно более детально, то вот ссылка на **[проект](http://o-s-a.net/os-engine.html)**

Хотелось бы перенести с сохранением совместимости с windows

Comment: Основная проблема  это WPF он windows only. Если сумеете переделать свой гуй, то задача переноса упрощается.